# how to call customized web form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

in windows application , when i want to call a customized form , i ueses this method :

```
    result frm = new result();
    frm.firstparameter = "first parameter";
    frm.secondparameter = "second parameter";
    frm.showdialog();
```

but in web application , i do not know how to handle it .

here is my webapplication source code :

in WebForm1.aspx.cs :

```
protected void sumbitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        result frm = new result();
        frm.firstparameter = "firstparameter";
        frm.secondparameter = "secondparameter";
        // frm.showpage() ???
       // Response.Redirect("~/result.aspx");

}
```

in result.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string Firstparameter = string.Empty;
    public string firstparameter 
    { 
        get{return Firstparameter;}

        set { Firstparameter = value; } 

    }

    private string Secondtparameter = string.Empty;
    public string secondparameter 
    { 
        get{return Secondparameter;}

        set { Secondparameter = value; } 

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         firstlbl.Text=Firstparameter;
     secondlbl.Text=Secondtparameter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET does not work that way. If you want to open one page after the other - you need to send a redirect request to do so. Of course you can also open popup, or make server transfer, but in your case redirect seems to be the best thing to do. Also note that parameters are not just passed into constructor or property - you need to attach them to the request, for example with query string.

So, in WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void sumbitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = string.Format("~/result.aspx?fp={0}&sp={1}", "firstparameter", "secondparameter");
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

In result.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         firstlbl.Text = Request["fp"];
         secondlbl.Text = Request["sp"];
    }
}
```

Note that this code leaves a lot of things out (parameter null handling for one), it just shows the point.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can also pass variables through session or cookies as well.